# How to build multiple ArrayLists in an async task using Gson string?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, gson, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to populate a RecyclerView with Mood objects. These objects are created on an Activity which is linked from the RecyclerView Activity (MoodsActivity) when a Mood is made it is saved to SharedPrefs via a Gson String. The Recycler isn't populating and I get a message saying the main thread may be doing too much work. 
I am now trying to implement an async task to take the Gson string which is a list of my mood objects, split the moods into separate ArrayLists and then return them.

I have tried to use an async task but I am struggling to implement it in a way to get it returned. It does not seem to like using shared preferences.

```
    try {
        ArrayList<Mood> historyList = gson.fromJson(history, ArrayList.class);
        ArrayList<String> moodNames = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> moodGenres = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Color> moodColors = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < historyList.size(); i++){
            moodNames.add(historyList.get(i).getName());
            moodGenres.add(historyList.get(i).getGenre());
            moodColors.add(historyList.get(i).getColor());
        }
        createRecycler(moodNames, moodGenres, moodColors);
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print("Couldn't load any moods");
    }


        View v = findViewById(buttonId);

        Button preferenceButton = (Button) v;

        preferenceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent preferencesPage = new Intent(view.getContext(), PreferencesActivity.class);
                startActivity(preferencesPage);
            }
        });

    }

    public void createRecycler(ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> genres, ArrayList<Color> colors){
    System.out.print("Reached");
    RecyclerView rView = findViewById(R.id.moodlistView);
    RecycleViewAdapter rAdapt = new RecycleViewAdapter(names, genres, colors, this);
    rView.setAdapter(rAdapt);
    rView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
```

My Async class below

```
    public class DoSomeTasks extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(getBaseContext().MODE_PRIVATE); //doesn't like using getPrefs

        try {

            String history = prefs.getString("history", "DEFAULT");

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ArrayList<Mood> historyList = gson.fromJson(history, ArrayList.class);
            ArrayList<String> moodNames = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> moodGenres = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Color> moodColors = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < historyList.size(); i++){
                moodNames.add(historyList.get(i).getName());
                moodGenres.add(historyList.get(i).getGenre());
                moodColors.add(historyList.get(i).getColor());
            }
            createRecycler(moodNames, moodGenres, moodColors);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.print("Couldn't load any moods");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: write a inner class, and all those local list make them member, and method "createRecycler(moodNames, moodGenres, moodColors) ", inside from doInBackground, you are accessing ui elements, access them only from main thread by using runOnUi or handler.

Comment: @notTdar I'm not sure what I would have my context as if I put createRecycler(...) into the inner class.